# ui.item.has() is always triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have problems with jQuery-UI and the ui.item Object. I've been [trying](http://jsfiddle.net/GGuqT/) to find out if a ui.item contains a element with a certain class, but it seems I'm using the wrong method.

*Code:*

```
$('.contain').sortable({
     start: function(e,ui) {
          if(ui.item.has('.nipple'))
              ui.item.css('background','red');
     }
}).disableSelection();
```

Can you please explain to my, why I'm wrong?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('.contain').sortable({
    start: function(e,ui) {
        ui.item.find('.nipple').css('background','red');
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GGuqT/2/

It just tries to find an elements with the `nipple` class inside the current `ui.item`. If it finds it then the style is applied.

I prefer this method as it's just one line and removes the need to check whether `.nipple` exists.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery **[.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)**

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a
>   descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

So I think you need to check for the `length` of returned objects

```
if(ui.item.has('.nipple').length > 0){
      //your code here
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you! But isn't this a little bit quick 'n dirty?

Comment: in your code you just 'll get list of matched elements not true or false value .. so i check for the count of these returned matched elements. and yea little bit quick 'n dirty